# Getting a Connection with DBCP via the Sybase Jconnect JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, apache-commons-dbcp, jconnect

I am trying to get a Connection in the following code and I keep getting an SQLException with the message "Login failed" and with the details "Specified database not found".

```
Connection con = null;    
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver");
dataSource.setUsername("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
dataSource.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
dataSource.setMaxActive(1);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(1);
dataSource.addConnectionProperty("databaseName", dbName);
dataSource.addConnectionProperty("servicename", dbName);
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2638");
con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I have also tried putting the dbName in url and setting it as a property in the url.

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2638/dbName");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2638?SERVICENAME=dbName");
```

None of it works.  It seems to be seeing the server just fine as the error changes if the url is wrong to just "Connection refused" message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you logon using that username and password using isql?

Comment: I can access the db with that username and password via dbisqlc.

Comment: I had this same problem.  Setting the CharacterEncoding parameter did the trick

Answer (score 4):

You could use SybDataSource, the following is enough:

```
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource;

SybDataSource dataSource = new SybDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setServerName("hostname");
dataSource.setPortNumber(5000);
con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL should be jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2638?ServiceName=dbName (perhaps it's case-sensitive)

http://www.razorsql.com/docs/help_sybase.html